# Ensure that C code function returns are not ignored?

Tags: c, return, static-analysis

Imagine there is a code like:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int divide(int a, int b, float *res)
{
        if (b == 0)
                return 0;
        *res = (float)a/b;
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
        float res;
        divide(2,5,&res);
        printf("%f", res);
        return 0;
}
```

The obvious mistake here is that the return of `divide()` is not being checked before printing the result.
Is there a way to detect such error automatically?
(like script, tool or service)
It would be very useful for a large codebase. I have not found any `gcc` or `clang` flags that could help. `cppcheck` also seems not to offer such feature.

Comment: Also `[[nodiscard]]` for C++ code bases, but I suppose this question is pure C?

Comment: Regarding `cppcheck`: We use MPLAB X IDE which comes with cppcheck to do MISRA checks. There I get a MISRA finding when I don't use (or cast to `void`) the return value of `memcpy` etc. Therefore I would expect cppcheck to be able to warn you.

Comment: There's an attribute in GCC called `warn_unused_result attribute`. You might want to use that. Add a macro definition at the top of your .c file.

`#define WARN_UNUSED __attribute__((warn_unused_result))`